# Join with a transpose of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, mysql-8.0, dynamic-pivot

The title doesn't much justice, but here is my table structure

```
    users table
    +---------+
    | user_id |
    +---------+
    |       1 |
    |       2 |
    |       3 |
    +---------+
```

```
kids table

+----------+---------+------------+
| child_id | user_id | child_name |
+----------+---------+------------+
|        1 |       1 | child_a    |
|        2 |       1 | child_b    |
|        3 |       2 | child_c    |
|        4 |       3 | child_x    |
|        5 |       3 | child_y    |
|        6 |       3 | child_z    |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

Now I want to transpose the `kids` table and join it with `users` table.

Expected output.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| user_id | child_1 | child_2 | child_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 | child_a | child_b |         |
|       2 | child_c |         |         |
|       3 | child_x | child_y | child_z |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

As you can see there are 3 columns of child information because the max number of children for a user is 3.

What I am able to do so far is the following, but then I will have to reach for some other languages to format this data again.

```
select user_id, group_concat(child_name) from kids group by user_id;
```

Any idea I could fetch expected result in mysql?

**EDIT**: I know that there will be maximum 3 children per user.

Comment: Main thing is that you would not know, how many columns you need to create to accommodate all childs. Rather than this use `group_concat` with `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: As you can see my question is exactly the same.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

@Shobi I believe you can do this by joining `kids` to `users` multiple times which should give you the names of the children, like this:

```
SELECT `u`.`user_id`,
    `k`.`child_name` AS `child_1`,
    `k2`.`child_name` AS `child_2`,
    `k3`.`child_name` AS `child_3`
FROM `users` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `kids` AS `k` ON `k`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `kids` AS `k2` ON `k2`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
    AND `k2`.`child_id` <> `k`.`child_id`
LEFT JOIN `kids` AS `k3` ON `k3`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
    AND `k3`.`child_id` <> `k2`.`child_id`
    AND `k3`.`child_id` <> `k`.`child_id`
GROUP BY `u`.`user_id`
```

[Here is a working example on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/795c0d/1)

NOTE: the above query works in MySQL <= 5.6. To get the same result in MySQL >= 5.7 you can use a version of the query that incorporates `ANY_VALUE()` which is listed as an appropriate use [here in the MySQL documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)

```
SELECT `u`.`user_id`,
    ANY_VALUE(`k`.`child_name`) AS `child_1`,
    ANY_VALUE(`k2`.`child_name`) AS `child_2`,
    ANY_VALUE(`k3`.`child_name`) AS `child_3`
FROM `users` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `kids` AS `k` ON `k`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `kids` AS `k2` ON `k2`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
    AND `k2`.`child_id` <> `k`.`child_id`
LEFT JOIN `kids` AS `k3` ON `k3`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
    AND `k3`.`child_id` <> `k2`.`child_id`
    AND `k3`.`child_id` <> `k`.`child_id`
GROUP BY `u`.`user_id`
ORDER BY `u`.`user_id`
```

[Here is a working example of this other version of the query in db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8wwzA7ZKihATzsE87TPA4Y/0)

Comment: this did work without the group by, i'm using mysql 8

Comment: There is no problem in sql for which the above is an appropriate solution :-(

Comment: @Strawberry could you elaborate a little more on why you say my solution doesn't work? I'm willing to accept the possibility that my query doesn't work, but looking at the expected result set from the OP and the result set my query returns, they are the same. Also, the OP indicated that my query did what he wanted. I'm just confused on why my query returns the result set the OP requested but you say that it doesn't.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You mean pivoting, the `users` table is not needed and might try the following method, which includes `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, to perform dynamically by using an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             DISTINCT
             CONCAT(
                    'MAX(CASE WHEN rn =', rn,
                    ' THEN child_name END) AS child_',rn
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY child_id) AS rn
     FROM kids                    
  ) k;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user_id,',@sql,
                   ' FROM 
                     (
                      SELECT *,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                             (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY child_id) AS rn
                        FROM kids                    
                     ) k
                    GROUP BY user_id'); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77e96074d76c918a9705868e4b59174a)</kbd>